# .load() not functioning properly in jquery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery

I am running the following simple script:

```
$(function(){
$('#divName').load('http://www.mydomain.com/someurl/');
});
```

In jQuery 1.8.3, it loads the external page (same domain name) into the #divName as expected.   In 1.9.1, it doesn't do anything.  Interestingly, if I run:

```
$('#divName').load('http://www.mydomain.com/someurl/');
```

in the console, it runs as expected; it just isn't doing it automatically on document.ready.  The jQuery migration plugin fixes the issue, however it doesn't give me any warnings that indicate what the problem is.

I have no urgent need to upgrade to 1.9, so for now I'm sticking to 1.8.3, but I'd sure like to know what changed in 1.9 that is causing this issue so that I am (a) aware for the future and (b) can go ahead and stick to the latest version as is my preference.

Comment: Have you tested this in different browsers? is the ajax request showing up in firebug or google chrome console? If it's same domain, you can replace `http://www.mydomain.com/someurl/` with `/someurl/`

Comment: Are there any other errors on your console - not when you run it manually but jsut loading the page with the code in question in the browser?

Comment: Tested in latest versions of Safari, Chrome and FF on Mac.  No AJAX request present in the console (developing in Chrome, but not present in the firebug console either).

Comment: prodigitalson, yes.  I'm a bit embarrassed to admit that there was an error thrown on a plugin in the page that I ignored, thinking it wouldn't be related, but sure enough, if I disable that plugin, MY script works fine.

Comment: That means your javascript isn't executing, make sure you aren't missing a closing <script> tag on your jQuery script inclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was being caused by an error in an unrelated plugin.  When the plugin was removed, the issue resolved itself.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible explanation I can think of for your scenario given the details is that your   `<div id="divName">` is being added through ajax on the DOM ready, hence it isn't available yet in the earlier part of your DOM ready handler.

Try doing `console.error($('#divName').length)` and seeing if the node exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the div physically exists in the HTML.